# Extending Knockout ViewModel with knockoutValidate results

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I've played a bit with Knockout validation and now I wondering is it possible to extend Knockout so that every view model have observable with list of errors which i get from validation?
In general i have

```
self.validationData = {
            name: ko.observable('').validateUpperEmail(),
            childName: ko.observable('').validateOther(),
            errorList: ko.observableArray([])
        };

var errors = ko.validation.group(self.validationData);

var showErrorMessages = function () {
            errors.showAllMessages(true);

            linqjs.from(errors()).distinct('$._latestValue').forEach(function(errorMessage) {
                self.validationData.errorList.push({ text: errorMessage() });
            });

        };
```

Question is: is there a way to populate errorList from some other place so that i can easily remove this property from every single view model and just use inherited one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use knockouts [extend feature](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

```
var baseModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.errorList = ko.observable('This is an example');
}

var childModel = function() { 
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable('Test1');
    self.childName = ko.observable('');
    ko.utils.extend(self, new baseModel());

}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aePDa/).

Comment: Thanks - i needed to add a bit more magic but this is great starting point